# How to use case here

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a SQL query to generate the below output from DB.

[image]

I am searching a condition like this

> When week_val is 1 then hour_val should come from week_val 2 row.
>   Otherwise hour_val comes from same row.

Comment: Please don't add commentary about voting in your questions - keep it to comments if you have to, and ideally not at all. Let people vote how they will, especially if you ask questions with no prior attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need subquery with CASE Statment

```
SELECT CASE WHEN week_val =1 THEN (SELECT TOP 1 hour_val FROM TABLE NAME WHERE week_val <> 1)
       ELSE  hour_val
       END
FROM  TableName
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: this assumes physical order of records are ascending, or there are only two records

Comment: @derloopkat yes right, since we have to filter data for first week only and select subsequent row data

Comment: The question says `hour_val should come from week_val 2 row` but that's not what your SQL does.

Comment: I think OP gets what he want from Ans

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT week_val, (CASE week_val 
  WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT hour_val FROM your_tbl WHERE week_val = 2) 
  ELSE hour_val) 
FROM your_tbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain there's going to be a row with week_val = 2 then you can avoid a subquery.

```
select week_val, 
       case week_val when 1 then lead(hour_val) over (order by week_val) else hour_val end as hour_val
  from t
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this - JOIN instead of subselect:

```
SELECT
    t1.week_val,
    CASE t1.week_val WHEN 1 THEN t2.hour_val ELSE t1.hour_val END AS hour_val 
  FROM
    table_name t1 LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t2.week_val = t1.week_val + 1
```